# web Bluetooth LE security

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, web-bluetooth

I'm creating a web app which connects to a control device. I want to secure it to make sure no one but the user can control it. for that I want to use LE secure connection pairing with numeric comparison. But my control device doesn't have a display, so I want to send the security code to my web app so the user can check the code's there and 'ok' the connection on the web app.
I wonder if this is possible and if I don't lose security while doing it this way

Answer (score 0):

How do you plan to send the security code to the web app? To do it programatically implies that you already have a secure channel to the device.

On devices without a screen I've seen the security code printed on a sticker. It isn't as secure as a code which can change every time a new pairing occurs but is better than no code at all.

If the device has a button you can require the user press it before pairing or other privileged actions are taken.